# Looping through list elements of an unordered list using xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I want to display the list elements of the ul but not the last one. I have used DOM nut it takes a long time.. Can Someone please give me the Xpath expression to solve this.
Please Provide the whole solution code.

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();  
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile($sel_image['snapdeal_content']);  
    $divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ul');  
    foreach($divs as $div) {  
    if ($div->getAttribute('class') == 'key-features') {  
        $li = $div->getElementsByTagName('li');  
        for($j=0;$j<$li->length-1;$j++){  
         echo "->".$li->item($j)->nodeValue;  
         echo "<br />";  
            }  

        }  

    }
```

Comment: Asking for "Please Provide the whole solution code" is like saying "do my work"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this excerpt to replace the for-loops in your solution. The `$li` array should contain all n-1 `<li>` elements of all `<ul>` enumerations in the document.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//ul[@class = "key-features"]/li[position() < last()]';
$li = $xpath->query($query);
```

Also see http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php and [XSL for-each: how to detect last node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738832/xsl-for-each-how-to-detect-last-node) .

Comment: it says "Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string".

Comment: Thanks 4 the demo.. it works.. I have used evaluate instead of query in xpath.. and it gives me the results.. :)

Comment: @JakeGould Please post your answer that you have provided in the link so that i can give you the credit.