# Picking the last in a sequence from a for-each-group with nested if

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've hacked my way around this issue, but I'd like to implement a better code. I'm trying to determine the last date where a non-zero financial event occurs. Note that this is a stripped and altered XML for brevity so excuse any formatting oddities. The actual XML I'm using has Change amounts from 1/1/2018 through 12/31/2029 with everything from 4/1/2018 to 12/31/2029 totaling to 0.

```
<Products>
  <Cost>
    <Company name="A"/>
    <Financials>
       <Change amount="-10000">
          <Date date="1/1/2018" dateindays="42734">
          <Type name="open">
       <Change>
       <Change amount="4500">
          <Date date="2/1/2018" dateindays="42765">
          <Type name="debit">
       </Change>
       <Change amount="4500">
          <Date date="3/1/2018" dateindays="42793">
          <Type name="debit">
       </Change>
       <Change amount="4500">
          <Date date="4/1/2018" dateindays="42824">
          <Type name="debit">
       </Change>
       <Change amount="-2000">
          <Date date="4/1/2018" dateindays="42824">
          <Type name="debit">
       <Change>
       <Change amount="-2500">
          <Date date="4/1/2018" dateindays="42824">
          <Type name="debit">
    </Financials>
  </Cost>
</Products>
```

In the above snippet I'd want the 3/1/2018 date, since the 4/1/2018 date totals to a 0 debit.

Using XSLT 2.0, I've used the following code to exclude the date of 4/1/2018, but I haven't figured a way to only return the 3/1/2018 date. Every thing I've tried has returned the 4/1/2018 as the last date in the series.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Products/Cost[Company/@name = 
    $Company]/Financials/Change[Type/@name = 'Debit']/Date" group-
    by="@dateindays">
  <xsl:sort select="@dateindays" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
  <xsl:variable name="actDate" select="@dateindays"/>
  <xsl:if test="sum(/Products/Cost[Company/@name = 
    $Company]/Financials/Change[Type/@name = 'Debit' and Date/@dateindays = 
    $actDate]/@amount) != 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="@date"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

As I said, I did some hacking (hidden cells in Excel), but I really want to handle it all in code as it appears this date might become required as part of later filtering within code.

Comment: Did you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738832/xsl-for-each-how-to-detect-last-node ?

Comment: I don't see how that is helpful. The crux of my issue is I need to exclude April from the data set and instead return March. The If statement is there to get the required April exclusion, but when I make that If into a for-each I'm getting all dates in my returned data set instead of all dates except April. In reality the node I want is randomly placed somewhere within 800+ Change nodes. Perhaps I just am missing what that thread is telling me.

Comment: I think I misread what you were asking for. I though you wanted to skip the last element, not the last "element-value".

Comment: After careful reading I have come to the conclusion that your dates must be in MM/DD/YYYY format. It would have been useful to tell us that. It would be even more useful to use a more standard format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the sum of the current-group for the check and then you need to output those elements in a variable and then take the first item in that variable value:

```
  <xsl:variable name="non-zero" as="element(Date)*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Products/Cost[Company/@name = 'A']/Financials/Change[Type/@name = 'debit']" group-by="Date/@dateindays">
          <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
          <xsl:variable name="actDate" select="@dateindays"/>
          <xsl:if test="sum(current-group()/@amount) != 0">
              <Date>{Date/@date}</Date>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$non-zero[1]"/>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoC

The `<Date>{Date/@date}</Date>` is XSLT 3, in XSLT 2 you need `<Date><xsl:value-of select="Date/@date"/></Date>`.

Comment: Well, it appears I have some odd data I didn't see before (not really surprising with a 6Mb XML I guess). I'm getting the fatal error: "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable $non-zero (<Date/>, <Date/>, ...)". I'm also seeing the warning message: "The only value that can pass type-checking is an empty sequence. Required item type of value of variable $non-zero is element(Q{}Date); supplied value has item type element(Q{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Date, Q{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}untyped)"

Comment: If your XSLT puts result elements into a namespace you need to adjust the variable code to `<Date xmlns=""><xsl:value-of select="Date/@date"/></Date>` to ensure the type I declared as `element(Date)*` is correct. It however sounds as if you don't have the asterisk in your code so make sure the variable is declared as a sequence of zero or more items with `element(Date)*` and not as a single element (as your error message suggests).

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that is similar to Martin's. I like Martin's better (+1), but since I'd already written it I'll go ahead and add it.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="company" select="'A'"/>

  <xsl:key name="changes" match="Change" use="Date/@dateindays"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Products/Cost[Company/@name = $company]/Financials"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Financials">
    <xsl:variable name="non-zero-days" as="xs:float*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Change" group-by="Date/@dateindays">
        <xsl:if test="sum(current-group()/@amount) != 0">          
          <xsl:sequence select="data(Date/@dateindays)"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>      
    </xsl:variable>
    <results>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('changes',string(max($non-zero-days)))[1]/Date/@date"/>
    </results>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<results>3/1/2018</results>
```

Working fiddle: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Yn/1

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a two-phase approach: group the data first, then do what you need to with the groups.

In the first phase, you transform

```
   <Change amount="4500">
      <Date date="4/1/2018" dateindays="42824">
      <Type name="debit">
   </Change>
   <Change amount="-2000">
      <Date date="4/1/2018" dateindays="42824">
      <Type name="debit">
   </Change>
   <Change amount="-2500">
      <Date date="4/1/2018" dateindays="42824">
      <Type name="debit">
   </Change>
```

to

```
<Date date="4/1/2018" dateindays="42824">
  <Change amount="4500">
          <Type name="debit">
  </Change>
  <Change amount="-2000">
          <Type name="debit">
  </Change>
  <Change amount="-2500">
          <Type name="debit">
  </Change>
</Date>
```

(which is a trivial use of xsl:for-each-group)

In the second phase, you apply filtering, for example `Date[sum(Change/@amount)!=0)][last()]`