# Identify position of the items in xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt

I have an Xml like below:

```
<data>
  <record id="1"/>
  <record id="2"/>
  <record id="3"/>
  <record id="4"/>
  <record id="5"/>
  <record id="6"/>
</data>
```

I want to print this xml as

```
**TRIM("1"-"2"-"3"-"4"-"5"-"6")**
```

I am using simple xsl like below

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*/record">
    <xsl:text>TRIM("</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:text>"-"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

the first item only requires `<xsl:text>TRIM("</xsl:text>` and last item requires `<xsl:text>)</xsl:text>`. How to achieve this in order to get the result **TRIM("1"-"2"-"3"-"4"-"5"-"6")**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT concat string, remove last comma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798269/xslt-concat-string-remove-last-comma)

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer. it is

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*/record">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:text>TRIM("</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:text>"-"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```