# Single XPath expression to concatenate values from multiple nodes

Tags: asp.net, xpath, concatenation, xpath-2.0

I need a single XPath expression to get the values from multiple nodes and concatenate them with a '>' separator character.

```
<products>
    <product ID="6">
        <name>2-in-1 Microsoft Surface Pro 4</name>
        <properties>
            <property name="subcategories">
                <value>Microsoft</value>
            </property>
            <property name="subsubcategories">
                <value>Surface</value>
            </property>
            <property name="size">
                <value></value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <variations/>
    </product>
</products>
```

I can get the value from a single node like so:

```
properties/property[@name='subcategories']
```

But how do I combine multiple nodes so the result would be:

```
"Microsoft>Surface" (or with a trailing ">" character if that's the only way)
```

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798269/xslt-concat-string-remove-last-comma), but that uses a template and I want a single XPath expression (so I can filter on it in my ASP.NET application using the `SelectSingleNode` method).

**update 1**

I tried @splash58's suggestion: `string-join(//property[@name="subcategories" or @name="subsubcategories"]/value, ">")`

But then I get the error:

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix,
>   variable, or user-defined function.

```
Dim responseString As String = "" 'this contains the XML document I load externally
productXML.LoadXml(responseString)
Dim mgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(productXML.NameTable)
mgr.AddNamespace("whatever", productXML.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

root = productXML.DocumentElement
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/products/product")
For Each node In nodeList

    If node.SelectSingleNode("string-join(//property[@name=""subcategories"" or @name=""subsubcategories""]/value, "">"")") IsNot Nothing Then
        'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

    End If

Next node
```

How can I fix that error?

Comment: As its name suggests `SelectSingleNode` will return a single node, which may be an element, or could be a text node. But it can't return a concatenated string value. It sounds like you need to use `SelectNodes`, and then do the concatenation of the selected nodes in your ASP.Net code instead.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I was hoping an XSL expression could return a single value concatenated from multiple nodes....but thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: in Xpath 2 - `string-join(//property/value,'>')` returns "Microsoft>Surface>"

Comment: @splash58: That looks like what I need, but is it also possible to define by name which properties specifically I need? In my case `subcategory` and `subsubcategory`

Comment: `string-join(//property[@name="subcategories" or @name="subsubcategories"]/value, ">")`

Comment: @splash58: thanks. I now get an error, I added it in update 1...could you have another look?

Comment: semms like your library has not full support of xpath 2

Comment: @splash58 Looks like you're right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net Need some 3rd party library for that...thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, no subject for thanking